База данных даёт пустой список
Пишу игрового телеграм-бота. И вот столкнулся с проблемой
Проблема на скрине

А также пробовал вывести в командную строку
Debug: []
Вот код:
main.py
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: 'обменять' in message.text.lower())
async def sell_donate(message: types.Message):
    try:
        _, amount = message.text.lower().split('обменять')
        amount = int(amount)
    except:
        amount = False

    if amount:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = select_user_table(user_id)
        if not user:
            NotUser(user_id, user)
        

        donate_balance = select_donate_table(user_id)
        print("Debug:", donate_balance)
        if donate_balance and donate_balance[0]:
            donate_balance = donate_balance[0][2]
        
            if donate_balance >= amount:
                await message.answer(f'Пополнение баланса на {amount * 10}e9...')
                try:
                    give_to(user_id, amount * 10000000000)
                    update_donate_sell_table(user_id, amount)
                    

                    updated_donate_balance = select_donate_table(user_id)
                    if updated_donate_balance and updated_donate_balance[0]:
                        updated_donate_balance = updated_donate_balance[0][2]
                    
                    await message.answer(f'Пополнение баланса на {amount * 10}e9 прошло успешно. '
                                         f'Твой текущий баланс: {updated_donate_balance} ByCoin')
                except Exception as e:
                    await message.answer(f'Что-то пошло не так. Попробуйте еще раз')
            else:
                await message.answer('У тебя нет стольки денег\n'
                                     f'Твой баланс: {donate_balance} ByCoin')
        else:
            await message.answer('У вас нет доната')
    else:
        await message.answer('Напиши в таком формате\n'
                             'обменять [Количество]')
    await message.delete()


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.lower().startswith('донат'))
async def donate_list_of_user(message: Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = select_user_table(user_id)
    if not user:
        NotUser(user_id, user)
    user = select_user_table(user_id)[0]
    donate_user = select_donate_table(user[0])[0][2]
    await message.answer(f'Ваш донат баланс: {donate_user} ByCoin\n'
                         f'1 ByCoin это 10 млрд$\n'
                         f'Вы можете продать донат командой: \n'
                         f'"Продать донат [Количество]"\n')

database.py

def create_donate_table():
    database = sqlite3.connect("game_database.db")
    cursor = database.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    create table if not exists donates(
        donat_id integer primary key autoincrement,
        user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        donate_balance integer NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    )
    ''')

def insert_donate_table(user_id):
    database = sqlite3.connect('game_database.db')
    cursor = database.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    insert into donates(user_id, donate_balance)
    values (
    (select user_id from users where telegram_id = ? )
    , ?)
    ''', (user_id, 0))
    database.commit()
    database.close()

def select_donate_table(user_id):
    database = sqlite3.connect('game_database.db')
    cursor = database.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
    select * from donates where user_id = ?
    ''', (user_id,))
    donate = cursor.fetchall()
    database.close()
    return donate

def update_donate_table(user_id, amount):
    database = sqlite3.connect('game_database.db')
    cursor = database.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
    update donates
    set donate_balance = ((select donate_balance from donates where user_id = ?) + ?)
    where user_id = ?;
    ''', (user_id, amount, user_id))
    database.commit()
    database.close()
    

def select_user_table(user_id):
    database = sqlite3.connect('game_database.db')
    cursor = database.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
    select * from users where telegram_id = ?
    ''', (user_id,))
    user = cursor.fetchall()
    database.close()
    return user



select_donate_table(user[0]) и select_donate_table(user_id) — а вас не смущает, что вы передаёте разные id?

Изменил добавил туда функцию select_user_table, просмотрите

Ну наличие столбца telegram_id видимо подразумевает, что user_id из таблицы и user_id из телеграма это таки разные id, так что id упомянутые в первом комментарии видимо таки действительно разные

Они могут такими быть и так, я делал другие функции засчёт этого и всё работало

У вас в базе данных несколько таблиц? Просто вы извлекаете данные в select_user_table из users , а в select_donate_table из donates

Я проблему уже решил, благодарю
